# Accessing Berkeley DB from different nodes

Tags: multithreading, process, locking, berkeley-db

I have a berkeley DB configured as a Concurrent Data Store. 
I was always accessing the database from one application with different numbers of Processes (till 64 Processes).

However, I have tried to use more processes to access the database (more than 64). Due to this fact, I have to use more than one machine, then every available machine has only 64 Processors.
The data itself is saved on NFS.
Accessing the data from two machines results the freezing of the applications.
Any Idea what Flags do I need to set to allow such a behavior? 
Till Now I have just used an environment with the flags : DB_CREATE, DB_INIT_MPOOL, DB_INIT_CDB, DB_THREAD.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because there's no protocol to lock a database page across multiple systems.  You have to confine your accesses to a single machine.  From the Berkeley DB FAQ:

> Berkeley DB is not designed to fully support multi-system concurrent access to a database environment on a shared disk available either on a network filesystem or a SAN.

Source: [Can Berkeley DB use NFS, SAN, or other remote/shared/network filesystems for databases and their environments?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/db-faq-095848.html#CanBerkeleyDBuseNFSSANorotherremotesharednetworkfilesystemsfordatabasesandtheirenvironments)